# Ubuntu 14.10 Intel Parallel Studio 2015 update 3 not supported

Tags: 14.04, 14.10, intel

I'm trying to install Intel Parallel Studio 2015 student edition on Ubuntu 14.10 using GUI installation. I get the message that my OS is not supported and latest supported Ubuntu version is 14.04.
Is there anything i can do with it ?

Comment: I don't know about other ways, but I would recommend you to install Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. It has 5 years of support term, will be supported until April 2019 (v. 14.10 - only until July 2015).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really **insist** on installing on 14.10 there is no guarantee it will work but you can try the following.

Because 14.10 uses mir there is no guarantee this will work. Also, you could possibly run into dependency issues which can be a headache. If you are adventurous and enjoy a challenge it may be kind of fun, however, you may end up having to reinstall because of a broken package management problem so **do so at your own risk!!**

**First**, add the 14.04 repository just in case there are any explicit dependencies needed.

Copy your existing sources list:

```
sudo cp /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/trusty-sources.list
```

Modify the copied file:

```
sudo sed -i 's/utopic/trusty/g' /etc/apt/sources.list.d/trusty-sources.list
```

**Next**, backup and then modify your /etc/lsb-release file:

```
sudo cp /etc/lsb-release /etc/lsbbackup
sudo sed -i 's/utopic/trusty/g;s/10/04/g' /etc/lsb-release; cat /etc/lsb-release
```

The output should look like this:

```
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=14.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=trusty
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 14.04"
```

Next, update apt-get:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Finally, install, re-install, or try running Parallel Studio and it should say your current version is supported.

---

The recommended approach, of course, is to go ahead and install 14.04LTS. You can even install it on a separate partition to make your set up a dual or even triple boot system. It is not uncommon for a computer to have 3 or even 4 linux operating systems installed on a single hard drive.